# static DataServiceContext in a static class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, wcf-data-services

I'm new to EF and it appears that I have made a mistake with it but I would like clarification.

My scenario:

- Winforms App (ClickOnce)
- A static class whose only responsibility is to update the DB via a DataServiceContext - single URI
- Only one control in the entire application uses this class

With the static class I created a single readonly instance of a DataServiceContext. There is also a GetMethod which gets the data using a ToList() on the context - this list is then used for data binding. I just need simple CRUD so there is a Save/Delete method, entities are passed in and updated.

As I've read a bit more about EF I understand that shared contexts are bad due to issues with concurrency. It seems that I would get away with a static context in this scenario as there would only ever be a single user accessing the same context per application instance or would I? I want to keep things as simple as possible. I'm starting to think perhaps I should turn the static class into a regular class with an immutable DataServiceContext instance shared between methods as a safeguard? Perhaps I should apply a using(DataServiceContext) within each method that makes a service call via SaveChanges to tighten things up even more? Do I need to do these things now or might it be YAGNI?

As I'm self taught here (no mentors), I might be in danger of going AWOL. I probably need some ground rules about EF my current reading as not led me to as yet. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't just about concurrency (but yes: that is an important concern) - it is also about correctness. If you have a single data-context, there are a few issues:

Firstly, memory: it will slowly grow over the life of the application, as more data is attached into the identity manager and change tracker.

Secondly - freshness: once things are attached to the data-context, you'll see the in-memory object - it may stop showing the up-to-date state of objects in the database

Thirdly - corruption: if anything goes wrong, the noral way of handling that is to simply rollback any in-flight changes, discard the data-context and report the error and/or retry the operation (on a fresh data-context); you can't keep using the old data-context - it is now in an undefined state

For all of these reasons, the general pattern is that you use a data-context only as a unit-of-work, to perform a single operation or a set of related / scoped operations. After that, *burn it and start again*.

Comment: @Jaycee will do when back at desk